# PCRE regex doesn't seem to work when used from shell with grep

Tags: regex, linux, grep, sh

I'm trying to output a node using a capture group for a decompiled DTS file using a PCRE regex passed into `grep`. I'm interested in the `key-samkey {(...)};` node only.

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong or can you point at any alternate methods to extract the node with its contents? I can't use `bash`'s `=~` operator, because there is a requirement that we only use `sh`.

I tried patterns:

`/(key-samkey {[.]*.+?[.]*};)/s`

`(key-samkey {[\s\S]*.+?(?=};))`

The exact command I'm using is:

`cat {input file} | grep -Po "{pattern}"`

Both of these patterns seem to work correctly on online regex testing websites with PCRE syntax, but fail when executed from the shell.

The file which I'm running pattern matching on is structured like this:

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {

    signature {

        key-samkey {
            required = "conf";
            algo = "sha256,rsa4096";
            rsa,r-squared = <xxxxxxxx>;
            rsa,modulus = <xxxxxxxx>;
            rsa,exponent = <0xxx 0xxxxxx>;
            rsa,n0-inverse = <0xxxxxxxxx>;
            rsa,num-bits = <0xxxxx>;
            key-name-hint = "samkey";
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: grep is a line-oriented tool. Use a proper parser instead

Comment: You may try (though it is not safe) `grep -Poz 'key-samkey\s*{[^{}]*}' file`. See https://ideone.com/5VbWqZ

Comment: Why the downvote? If you think it can be done in a better way than `grep`, then please explain. It will always be a simple file with a single node and its used in a shell script which automates something that was done by hand until now. I thought that doing "proper" parsing would be overkill for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. A regular expression you can use is

`(?s)(key-samkey \{.+?\};)`.

- `(?s)`: The dot `.` matches everything (DOTALL)
- `\{` and `\}`: You have to escape these, because they have special meaning in a regex.
- `.+?`: matches everything it can non-greedy, meaning, in this case, everything up to the first `};`

Then use the `-z` switch of grep, this replaces newlines in the input with null-bytes, so that grep sees the input as one big line.

Example: I stored your example in the file `test.file`:

```
> grep -Pzo '(?s)(key-samkey \{.+?\};)' test.file

key-samkey {
            required = "conf";
            algo = "sha256,rsa4096";
            rsa,r-squared = <xxxxxxxx>;
            rsa,modulus = <xxxxxxxx>;
            rsa,exponent = <0xxx 0xxxxxx>;
            rsa,n0-inverse = <0xxxxxxxxx>;
            rsa,num-bits = <0xxxxx>;
            key-name-hint = "samkey";
        };
```

Comment: About escaping curly brackets: the closing curly bracket isn't a special character at all (like the closing square bracket). The opening curly bracket is a special character, but with some regex engine (including PCRE) you can omit the escape when there's no risk of confusion (with a quantifier `{m,n}` or `{n}`).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yep, but you write regexen not only to be executed, but also to be read by yourself in a week and others down the road, escaping special characters that are not in `[]` makes it clear without further parsing efforts in your head how to read them.

Answer (score 3):

More simple to define a range of lines with sed:

```
sed -n '/key-samkey {/,/};/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

the answers provided will do the trick for you. However, if you don't want to change your regular expression I found a convenient way to execute PCRE expressions without pain. You can try opening your DTS file with Sublime (COMMAND+F in MAC), make sure *Regular expression* option is turned on, and paste your expression (I just tried on your example). Click "Find All" and Copy the result.